# @apollo/client with credentials doens'nt work

Tags: next.js, graphql, cors, apollo-client, apollo-server

I'm using this code to set up my nextJS app with apollo graphql,

`const client = new ApolloClient({uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',cache,credentials: 'include',});`

But the issue is that im getting the cors error even when ive set it up in my backend. The cors error appears only in the network tab and not in the console. The code works when i don't use the credentials option. I've also tried this,

`const httpLink = new HttpLink({uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',credentials: 'include',});const client = new ApolloClient({cache,link: httpLink,});`

I've looked up the documentation and everything but it just won't work with the credentials option in the configuration.

```
import { print } from 'graphql';

const query = gql`
  query MyQuery { ... }
`;

fetch(uri, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    accept: '*/*',
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  },
  credentials: 'include',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query: print(query),
    operationName: 'MyQuery', // replace with the operation name in the query you send
  })
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
```

I've tried this method to run queries and this works.

I've tried a POST request with graphql and it works but the apollo client in the same app doesnt work.

Comment: Can you post how your cors is setup on your backend?

Comment: You can check anything related to it here. https://github.com/dawudarif/todo-app

Answer (score 0):

According to the Apollo docs, you should put your cors settings here:
[Apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/security/cors/#configuring-cors-options-for-apollo-server)

```
app.use(
  '/graphql',
  cors({ origin: ['https://www.your-app.example', 'https://studio.apollographql.com'] }),
  json(),
  expressMiddleware(server),
);
```

In your example, it should look like this:

```
const corsOptions = {
  credentials: true,
  origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
};

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const app = express();

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
cors: corsOptions
});
```

And if you are using apollo-server-express package, then it should look like this:

```
const app = express();
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
  });

  await server.start();

  server.applyMiddleware({
    app,
    cors: {
      credentials: true,
      origin: [process.env.ORIGIN as string, "studio.apollographql.com"],
    },
  });
```

Don't forget to restart your server after this change.